# "Microsoft.Bot.Schema.APIException" exception in Telegram Bot deploy on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service, telegram-bot

I have gotten the following exception in App Insights most of the times from our created telegram bot which is developed in Microsoft Bot Framework and deployed on Azure:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.APIException: at
TelegramChannel.Controllers.TelegramController+<Post>d__0.MoveNext
(TelegramChannel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null:
C:\a\1\s\Channels\TelegramChannel\Controllers\TelegramController.cs: 115)
```

Anybody knows about this?

Comment: show the code or report as bug to MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As our bot was published on Azure, when I created a new website on Azure and 
published it again, it worked properly!